# push Notification not getting in android $ ios .i make one cron regarding this in order service

Tags: java

Acceptance Criteria

PRE-REQUISITE: For all Pick up from store orders

WHEN: the order becomes ready to collect

THEN: User must recieve Push notifications as reminders using the below logic:

HAPPY FLOW:

Push notification reminders have to be triggered to customer on day the order is ready to collect in the format mentioned below: D1 = Day when order is ready for pick up

REMINDER 1 : Hey ! This is a reminder to pick up your order #1234567890  from  before  When to trigger: If D + 1, where D is day when order was ready to collect

REMINDER 2,3 : Hey ! Your order #1234567890  is waiting for you. Please pick it up from  before When to trigger: On D+3 & D+5

REMINDER 4 : Hey ! Your order #1234567890  is waiting for you. Please pick it up from  before  to avoid order cancellation When to trigger: On D6

In total , 4 Push notifications to be triggered until day 6 on D+1, D+3, D+5 & D6

Push notification to be different on day 6 alerting customers on cancellation

i write this code in notification service -> but still not able to get push notification .

else if (customerNotifyRequest.getOrderType().equals(OrderType.CLICK_COLLECT) || customerNotifyRequest.getOrderType().equals(OrderType.RESERVE_COLLECT)) {
if (customerNotifyRequest.getStatus().equals(OrderStatus.READY_TO_COLLECT)) {
title = "ORDER READY TO PICK-UP";
if(customerNotifyRequest.getDaysBehind()==1)
message.append("Hey ").append(customerNotifyRequest.getUsername()).append("! This is a reminder to pick up your order #").append(customerNotifyRequest.getOrderId()).append("  from ").append(customerNotifyRequest.getStoreName()).append(" before ").append(customerNotifyRequest.getBeforeDate());
else if(customerNotifyRequest.getDaysBehind()==3 || customerNotifyRequest.getDaysBehind()==5)
message.append("Hey ").append(customerNotifyRequest.getUsername()).append("! Your order #").append(customerNotifyRequest.getOrderId()).append("  is waiting for you. Please pick it up from ").append(customerNotifyRequest.getStoreName()).append(" before ").append(customerNotifyRequest.getBeforeDate());
else if(customerNotifyRequest.getDaysBehind()==6)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.